# Ubuntu 14.04 won't install i386 libraries

Tags: 14.04, dependencies, 32-bit, sh

Alright community, hello there and please help me.  I've been trying to run a game from GOG, and their support nor that community have been able to help me.  It is a recurrent issue and it got a little worse after I changed to Ubuntu 16.04 and tried to return to 14.04.02.  It won't install some of the i386 libraries.

[I've tried only through command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9Pa3.png)

And now it really doesn't matter what I do, it keeps me from adding those libraries.  Obviously I am not well versed in these matters, but even trying what I've found in some threads here hasn't helped; anyone can help me understand?

Comment: DO NOT post screenshots of text output from terminal, copy and paste it in your question and format it. --- Did you try, as suggested, `sudo apt -f install` ?

Comment: What does this mean : "after I changed to Ubuntu 16.04 and tried to return to 14.04.02." Are you trying to undo an upgrade from 14 to 16?